# How to get the data from child component into the parent component when the form submit button is in the parent component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I have two components:

Parent component HTML:

```
<parent-component>
    <child-component [input]="inputValue"> </child-component>
    <child-component [input]="inputValue"> </child-component>

    <button mat-stroked-button> Submit </button>
</parent-component>
```

Parent component TS:
here I was trying to test if ViewChild wokrs correctly and it is. I get a property value from child in my parent component.

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) childReference;
  parentString: string;

  constructor(
    private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.parentString = this.childReference.exampleChild;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

In my child component html I have a couple of `<mat-form-field>` inputs:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <mat-form-field>
           <input matInput formControlName="myInput">
      </mat-form-field>
     <mat-form-field>
           <input matInput formControlName="myInput2">
      </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

But how to properly get an matInput values from child component in the parent component when the actual submit button is in the parent?

Comment: Submit in Parent and want data in Child?

Comment: If it's a question, I have an inputs in child and I want to get those input values in parent when the submit button is in the parent.

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz So I can have a look at?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `public getData() {}` function on the child component that returns the data of the child component. The parent submit would look something like

```
public submit() {
    const data = this.childReference.getData();
    // do whatever you need to do with the data from child
}
```

It looks like you're trying to get data from multiple children in your example, in which case you'll have to use [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren).

I would also consider making the parent have an [Angular form](https://angular.io/guide/forms#create-an-initial-html-form-template), and restructuring your components so that the child components are custom inputs that work with that form. See the custom input component called `state-selector` created in [this tutorial](https://blog.angulartraining.com/tutorial-custom-form-controls-with-angular-22fc31c8c4cc)

Comment: With a `ViewChild@` I get a child information only from just the first child. Somewhy, second child brings me empty strings..

Answer (score 0):

If you have redux setup with your project. You should go with redux. Redux is buildup to solve similar type of problems.